# C# Type suffix for decimal

Tags: c#, types, double, decimal, type-inference

I don't know what the correct wording is for what I am trying to achieve so it may already be posted online. Please be kind if it is.

Ok so basically I have this method.

```
public static T IsNull<T>(IDataReader dr, String name, T nullValue)
{
    return Helpers.IsNull(dr, dr.GetOrdinal(name), nullValue);
}

public static T IsNull<T>(IDataReader dr, Int32 index, T nullValue)
{
    if (dr.IsDBNull(index))
    {
        return nullValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)dr.GetValue(index);
    }
}
```

Being called as `Helpers.IsNull(dr, "UnitWholeSale", 0d)` and the error I am getting is "Cannot convert from double to decimal".

Now I know I can use `decimal.Zero` but is there some way that I can simply go 0dec or something similar? I just hate those long shortcut values (especially when you are calling a constructor with 20 parameters).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`0m` is how you say `(decimal)0` because `m` is the suffix that means `decimal`.

Other suffixes are `f` for `float`, `d` for `double`, `u` for `unsigned`, and `l` for `long`. They can be either upper- or lower-case and `u` can be combined with `l` in either order to make a `ulong`.

Although the suffixes are not case-sensitive, keep in mind what it says in the C# language specification, section 2.4.4.2:

> As a matter of style, it is suggested that “L” be used instead of “l” when writing literals of type long, since it is easy to confuse the letter “l” with the digit “1”.

Comment: And be careful with that lower-case el. Quick, is 5432l == 54321 true or false? :-)

Comment: @Eric: I've been blessed with a font that makes it easy to distinguish a one from an ell, but I've quoted the spec's suggestion to use uppercase because you reminded me.

Answer (score 23):

`0m` will give you a `decimal` 0 value.

For the sake of completeness,

```
0.0 - double
0f  - float
0m  - decimal
```

Answer (score 3):

```
float value = 0f || 0.0f || (float)0;
double value = 0d || 0.0d || (double)0;
decimal value = 0m || 0.0m || (decimal)0;
```

Be aware that each last example is a cast and therefor can lose precision

Answer (score 1):

`M` is the suffix for `decimal` values, e.g. `200.32M` is considered to be of type `decimal` to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `0d`, you can use `0m` for decimal values.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `nullValue` is really `defaultvalue`, otherwise you could just do

```
public static T IsNull<T>(IDataReader dr, Int32 index)
{
    if (dr.IsDBNull(index))
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)dr.GetValue(index);
    }
}
```

Also looking more closely at your method you probably want a convertible value and use [**`Convert.ChangeType()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx) , I don't think the simple casting would work for all types:

```
public static T IsNull<T>(IDataReader dr, Int32 index) where T: IConvertible 
{
    if (dr.IsDBNull(index))
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(dr.GetValue(index), typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u for that tip... I was not aware of such functionality. nullValue would be better expressed as defaultValue since I never really use anything other then the default.

Comment: @Maxim: Updated with a more generic version

Comment: Thanks again mate, I love code review when you actually learn something.

Answer (score 0):

Use `0.0m` instead - `m` denotes `decimal`.

Comment: 0.0m?  Why not just 0m?